# Missing sample apps on Alljoyn-thin SDK/cloned repository

Tags: alljoyn

I'm running few alljoyn-thin apps on my linux system but could not find few of the sample apps which has been published on the website. Namely apps like [Chat](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/chat)
, [Configuration](https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/run-sample-apps/config) etc.

In fact, I'm not able to find any of "services samples" mentioned on the https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/thin-linux .
Could not find 'sample_app' folder either.

I tried with both 15.09 and 16.04 sources and found above missing in both cases.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the following repositories:

```
git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/core/ajtcl
```

this should have an additional sample about config (under services/config/samples).

```
git clone https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/services/sample_apps
```

should contains another set of samples.

In any case, I'd suggest to take a look at this:
https://git.allseenalliance.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/

Comment: @dkumar does it helped?